# Managing users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am attempting to manage users in my app that uses Devise for the authentication. I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) in order to create a UsersController to allow me to do so. However, when I attempt to sign out, it says that the path `/d/users/sign_out` cannot be found. Is there anything else I need to add to get this to work?

EDIT: My routes look like:

```
devise_for :users. :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :users do
  # stuff here
end
```

When I run `rake routes`, it gives me, for the `destroy_user_session_path`:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /d/users/sign_out(.:format)  {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

When I remove the path_prefix part, it attempts to 'show' a user with the ID sign_out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link_to "sign_out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

do you have the method `:delete` in your view?

Comment: Yep, I have `:method => :delete` in my view.

Comment: it's very strange. i just checked your last edits in post - it's just worked as followed with `method: :delete`, but without it Devise search user - exactly as in yours issue. could you please paste your link_to here?

Also, you may check config for sign_out at devise initializer at `config.sign_out_via` (line 194 for 2.0.0)

Comment: also check loading of rails javascript file that handle such links. for Rails >= 3.1 you should have loaded `//= require jquery_ujs` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`